# About _Users._Disabled

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I kept reading the docs and I can't find this.

I need to have some users Active and others Inactive.

Can I use _Users._Disabled for that?
Would it be safe?

We use OpenEdge 11.6.3, Windows 2016 server, Windows 8.1 and 10 workstations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

We also support Oracle and SQL databases thru the DataServer products so have limited use for the _user table and have always had our own user table.

This [knowledge base article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Customer-usable-fields-in-User-system-table) indicates that 'metaschema' fields are reserved for Progress' use. Metaschema being the wider name for any system table or view starting with an underscore. The _user-misc field can be appropriated for custom use.

This however conflicts with another [knowledge base article](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/What-are-the-active-fields-of-user-table) indicating that the only active fields are:

- _Userid
- _Password
- _TenantId
- _Domain-name
- _sql-only-user

Although it is, along with other 'inactive' fields returned by the [OpenEdge.Security.Provider.UserTableAuthProvider](https://github.com/consultingwerk/ADE-Sourcecode/blob/73943e8045bec62b3b45717c083a249acdea9320/src/seclib/OpenEdge/Security/Provider/UserTableAuthProvider.cls).

So I would tend to say, use it.

Comment: That really helps, thank you!
I hadn't found the second article, which is more recent. I guess the first one needs some update.

I was trying the use in a copy of the database and had no problem. The article gives me some "legal base" to try in production, and may Pachamama help me.

I would also prefer to use my own tables.

Thanks again.